# Migration WFE and APP servers

Tags: migration

I have a 2-Tier sharepoint 2010 architecture :  Application Server and Web Server running on same server and separate Database server. Need to move WFE and App servers to the existing DB server. (to have all roles at one server). What is the easiest way to do this? Thinking about installing new shrepoint to db server and connect to exisiting DB, but worry about the success of this idea? can be there any conflicts in names and configuration....

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you would want to move the sharepoint server to the database server? unless you have 2 phyiscal servers and your WFE/App SharePoint server is underspecc'd and you don't have any other resources? As it stands you've got the recommended deployment for the architecture.

If you're going to go about this you'll need to install SharePoint on the database server and join it to the farm as an additional server as you suggest. It shouldn't conflict with specifically with any naming conventions (untested but I can't see why it would), you'll just need to shift all the application roles over to that server then when you're done remove the existing SharePoint server from the farm and you'll end up with this 1 single server.

Comment: And should I redeploy all custom solutions on new server or not...?

Comment: yes you would have to redeploy the solutions, using central administration and you might need to get them out of C:\assembly if you are missing dlls